# Adding a record to a table requires entering a value belongs to another table MS Access 2016

Tags: ms-access

I am designing a database for a store using Microsoft Access 2016. There are 3 tables i.e. Categories, Subcategories and Products. Each category has multiple subcategories and each subcategory has multiple products. I have built 2 forms; the first one is to create a new category and the second one is to create a new subcategory. Everything was going well until I created a new form to create a new product. In this form there are 2 combo boxes; the first one is for the user to choose the category of the product, and the second one is to choose the subcategory of that chosen category. Combo boxes are working like expected. When I fill in all the text boxes (Product fields) in this form and press add a product it says that I should enter a value in a field (Set to required) which is existed in the Category table! It seems like it is trying to create a new record (category) in the Category table! Even though, from the combo box, I am choosing a category which is already existed in the Category table. After some investigation I also found out that combo boxes are returning the ID of the category not the category name itself. Therefore access is trying to create a new category and fill in the category name with the related ID. Now I am stuck and don't know what to do. How can I add a new product using the mentioned combo box combination? What am I doing wrong? Please ask me questions if you need more clarifications.

**Edit1:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Product form:

[image]

Category combo box properties:

[image]

Its row source:

[image]

Subcategory combo box properties:

[image]

Its row source:

[image]

When I first wrote the question the Control Source of the two combo boxes were Category_Name and Subcategory_Name. I changed them to Category_ID and Subcategory_ID. Now I am getting the following message:

[image]

**Edit2:**

The RecordSource of the form:

[image]

Comment: Subcategories table should store category ID. Products table should store subcategory ID, no need to also store category ID. Comboboxes should be set up to display descriptive text but save IDs. You would have to provide  table structure (field names and types) and combobox property settings for us to analyze what you are doing wrong.

Comment: June7 recommendations are correct, but it is still okay to have a Cateogry combobox on the Product form if it is only for filtering the Subcategory combobox selection list.  In that case, the **Category combobx should be unbound**.

Comment: I have edited the question please have a look

Comment: @CPerkins Oh, I am not familiar with the terms bound and unbound! How can I check if a combo box is bound or not and what is the difference? Another thing, in the product form I need to know the chosen category and subcategory to be able to calculate the custom SKU for the related product.

Comment: *Bound* means that the ControlSource of the control has the name of a field from the form's RecordSource query.  *Unbound* means that the ControlSource is blank, so that it does not automatically update a field.  To use the Category ComboBox as a filter for the subcategory, and to calculate an SKU from selected category and subcategory will (most likely) involve VBA, or at least advanced techniques.  I perceive a need to learn more about Access forms, perhaps a book or online tutorials, etc.  This question is likely too broad for StackOverflow which is not meant to walk through all details.

Comment: @CPerkins I have already solved the part related to the SKU calculations and I have VBA background so this should not be a problem. My main problem is why can't I create a new product?

Comment: What is the **RecordSource** of the form? That's the primary query which retrieves and/or updates data in the Product table. The combobox RowSource only specifies what list items are available for selections; they do not indicate what table is updated.  The RecordSource query will also be the cause of the error message regarding one-to-many relationships.  You are likely attempting to join multiple tables together in the form's query, but not only is that unnecessary but also incorrect.  **Only reference the Product table**, since the related table ID's are obtained from the ComboBoxes.

Comment: @CPerkins I have just referenced only the Product table and made the Category combo box unbound. Thank you now I am able to create a new product! but still have a small problem. Now the Category combo box is not showing the category name of the already stored products when I navigate through them in the form!

Comment: **Short answer is that you'll need to program custom binding using event handlers: Start with `Form_Current()` to get category.**  Thorough form logic should eventually lead to questions about what happens when editing an existing record... what does it mean to select a new Category?  Should it immediately nullify the existing Subcategory value or leave the existing value until it is changed explicitly?  Can the user tolerate a disconnect between the two?

Comment: Glad I could help.  The more you program Forms, you will develop a better feel for the default data binding and how it relates to normalized table design, etc.  But despite knowing VBA, my previous advice about tutorials and/or books still stands, since the struggle with this form and the continued line of questions still indicate a lack of understanding about how Access forms work, both their strengths and limitations.

Comment: @CPerkins thank you for your suggestions. Please sum up your comments and post your answer so I mark it as the right one.